# autosearch plugin in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Am having a list box now it have to auto search or autocomplete in drop down or text box so is there any plug-in available in jquery

```
<select data-placeholder="please select..." id="search">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>

    </select>
```

Any link available or some example is there???????

Answer (score 0):

Here try bootstrap typeahead:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

or the bootstrap selectpicker:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @user3032277 how about this?

Comment: how to do this multiple search by comma(,)